# Embed ACF URL Field in WP title field

Tags: urls

I have a small listing-type block on a website that displays editorial titles which when clicked I want a new browser to open and the resulting page display the external page related to the clicked title in a new browser window.

I created a ACF field called title_link and this was working. However, I have just stripped back the Custom Fields to make the UX more intuitive. It broke, I have played with the code, I know it’s simple but I have gone blank as to why.

```
<a href=<<? php get_field( 'title_link', $this->post->ID );?> target="_blank"><?php echo get_the_title( $this->post->ID );?></a>
```

All and any help received gratefully.

G

Comment: Is that `<<? php` just a typo in the question? And the `href` value needs to be in quotes - `href="value"`.

Answer (score 0):

Have solved it.

```
       <div><a target="_blank" href="<?php the_field('title_link', $this->post->ID); ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php echo get_the_title( $this->post->ID );//$title; ?>"><?php echo get_the_title( $this->post->ID ); //$title; ?></a>   </div>
```